# MS Access: Concatenate two fields into existing field

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a form with 5 combo boxes.  As an example (maybe a poor one):

CBO1 is username (in table), CBO2 is Lastname (value list).

I would like to concatenate CBO1 and CBO2, and save as CBO1 to my table.  Is this possible?  Thank you.

Comment: Let's think a few more steps down the path... Say you need to edit this record in the future.  Are you then going to have to split out these saved values into each of the combo boxes again?  if so why save to one field?  You could write a query/view which concats the fields together for easier reporting/analysis if you must....  My point here is keep separate concepts(objects/fields) separate, especially if the system allows for separate entry.

Comment: Thanks @xQbert.  I believe you are suggesting to create a new field for the concatenated value.  I have thought of this.   This is an existing database, and I am trying to do what makes sense for the situation.  Would you consider my thoughts bad practice?

Comment: Not a new field in your table, but a calculated field in a query.

Comment: @user2796515 . I'm saying keep the field values entered in separate places in the table structure.  Why do you need them together? for reporting?  if so write a query that combines the two fields and base the report on the query. Combining the fields into one and storing that combined value doesn't make sense IF (and only if) a user can ever edit the data.  If the data entry can't EVER (and think about oops I need to correct something here) be edited in the same fashion it's entered, then you could get away with one field; but it still rubs me the wrong way.

Comment: Thanks @Andre451.  Currently this field is being used for reports, queries, etc.  I would like the user to be able to choose from the two combo boxes to edit future values of the "username" field.  Are you suggesting I point the existing reports, etc, to this new calculated field in the query?

Comment: @xQbert. Thanks.  The new field value is used in reports, queries, and to populate comboboxes in other forms.  Now, there is a new requirement for the "username" field.  The "lastname" field is the new requirement and is not saved to a table  - it is a value list.  Hope this helps explain my need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the form field CBO2 add an event procedure "after Update".

`Private Sub CBO2_AfterUpdate()
   Me.CBO1 = Me.CBO1 & " " & Me.CBO2
End Sub`

Comment: This appears to do what I need it to do.  I will do some testing to try and catch unintended consequences of this method.  But you have answered my question - thanks and thank you to all who helped.